# Django: Can I have access to client cookies on first page load?

Tags: django, cookies

I need to read a cookie set by Google in order to render my homepage view. But I noticed that, on first load, the object `request.COOKIES` is always empty.

I'm not sure if this is normal, my logic says "when you have a new visitor, all cookies are empty by default, so this is normal", but then, how do tools like Google Optimize work?

Is there any way to wait for all client cookies to be set before rendering a view in Django? or will this never be something you'll want to do?

I'm having a rough time trying to make an A/B to test work, but I'm starting to think that my approach of reading the cookies on first load was destined to never work.

Can someone give me some piece of advice here?

Comment: You only receive cookies from the *same domain* as the one that has set that cookie. Take a look at cross-site cooking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_cooking

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @WillemVanOnsem, I've read that Wikipedia entry and I understand that in order to avoid this type of attacks, nobody can send a cookie directly to the server through the client. But, this is the reason why on first load the cookies are empty? If to avoiding this type of attacks?

Comment: the browser will only send the cookies stored for the domain on which your server is running. So cookies of another domain, are never send to the webserver.

Comment: Oooooooh, that's insightful. Thank you so much @WillemVanOnsem, I really appreciate your answer.